# Using Consul for hadoop hdfs namenode failover

Tags: hadoop, dns, hdfs, consul, namenode

I'm trying to work with Hadoop Java Client and I'm using [Consul](https://www.consul.io) for routing to current active name node in my cluster. My cluster is cloudera and using HA.
When active namenode is changed by hadoop Consul immediately also changing resolution to new active namenode.
I want to connect to HDFS from outside of hadoop cluster.

I'm trying very simple code in loop, without any specific configuration.

```
    try {
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            conf.set("fs.defaultFS", activeHdfsNameNodeBehindConsul);
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
            Path pathToDirectory = new Path("/user/");
            if (!fs.exists(pathToDirectory)) {
                System.out.println("HDFS PATH EXIST");
            } else{
                System.out.println("HDFS PATH NOT EXIST");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
```

When I'm starting to run I see in logs that name node is resolved correctly but when I'm doing manual failover I get following error:

```
Operation category READ is not supported in state standby. Visit https://s.apache.org/sbnn-error
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.StandbyState.checkOperation(StandbyState.java:88)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode$NameNodeHAContext.checkOperation(NameNode.java:1836)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkOperation(FSNamesystem.java:1433)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getFileInfo(FSNamesystem.java:4245)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getFileInfo(NameNodeRpcServer.java:897)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.getFileInfo(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:528)
```

Looks like Hadoop client still trying to connect to previous stored IP and not to already changed to ip of new active namenode.

I saw many similar questions about the problem of one URI for HA namenodes  but without any solution. Now I have the solution but need to know how to clean IP cache of hadoop client.

Is someone knows how to disable internal cache IP resolution for HDFS client in order that it will perform lookup for the IP of active namenode each call?